# Azure EventGrid Advanced filtering isNotNull operator

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-eventgrid

any idea why it is not possible to select the IsNotNull operator through the portal?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-filtering#isnotnull

I've tried configuring that in the ARM template, but I get the following error

`InvalidRequest: The following Advanced filter operator types are only supported on api-versions newer than Microsoft.Azure.Events.ResourceProvider.Common.ApiVersion`.

Any idea?
Thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please, change the version to **api-version=2020-10-15-preview**

Comment: great! I was able to deploy successfully! Unfortunately the filter is not visible on the portal... so it gets quite confusing...

Comment: Do you mind me asking where you find this out, since it's not even available in the official doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventgrid/eventsubscriptions?tabs=json). Do you have any link or preview article?
Thanks
Fabrizio

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventgrid/version2020-10-15-preview/eventsubscriptions

Comment: I confirm that this api-version=2020-10-15-preview works. Every other versions fails.